# Print combinations of balanced parentheses

Tags: ruby, recursion, balanced-delimiters

Solved the below problem. Would love to hear your feedback, especially on performance improvements (granted, the solution should remain recursive).

Especially concerned about the `obj.include? elem` check I had to add to prevent duplicates. Don't know a better way to do without it.

```
# Implement an algorithm to print all valid (e.g., properly 
# opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses.
# EXAMPLE
# Input: 3
# Output: ((())), (()()), (())(), ()(()), ()()()

def brackets(n)
  return ["()"] if n == 1

  brackets(n-1).each_with_object([]) do |p, obj|
    for i in 0..p.length
      # stuff the "()" in every possible position within 'p'
      elem = p.dup.insert(i, "()")
      obj << elem unless obj.include? elem
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a nice solution!

One thing that might speed things up a little would be to use a `Set`; no need for the `include?` then. Just call `to_a` on it at the end (or don't, and return a `Set` - still fits the task).

Also, I'd use `p.length.times { |i| ... }` instead of a `for` loop, and make a couple of variable names a little more descriptive (`p`, for instance, is not a very descriptive name).

```
require 'set'

def brackets(n)
  return ["()"] if n == 1

  brackets(n-1).each_with_object(Set.new) do |str, set|
    str.length.times do |i|
      set << str.dup.insert(i, "()")
    end
  end.to_a
end
```

Or, without converting to an array:

```
def brackets(n)
  return Set.new(["()"]) if n == 1

  brackets(n-1).each_with_object(Set.new) do |str, set|
    str.length.times do |i|
      set << str.dup.insert(i, "()")
    end
  end
end

brackets(3) # => #<Set: {"()()()", "(())()", "()(())", "(()())", "((()))"}>
```

Might also be nice to avoid the duplicated `"()"` string. You could make it an argument, so the method can be used for other "pairs", e.g:

```
def brackets(n, pair = "()")
  return Set.new([pair]) if n == 1

  brackets(n-1, pair).each_with_object(Set.new) do |str, set|
    str.length.times do |i|
      set << str.dup.insert(i, pair)
    end
  end
end

brackets(3, "<>") # => #<Set: {"<><><>", "<<>><>", "<><<>>", "<<><>>", "<<<>>>"}>
```

Or you can simply make it a constant, like `SINGLE_PAIR = "()".freeze`.

Comment: Ah, excellent suggestion on the use of a `Set`! Thanks!